# how to get the associated unique ID of the recently added entry in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need some workaround/solutions for my ajax issue

i have this simple `<html>`

```
<textarea class="msg"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>

<div class="messages">
 <?php some php while loop here to display all submitted messages?>
</div>
```

when i click submit, this ajax gets the value of `<textarea>` and submits the data into messages.php

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.submit', function () {
    var msg = $('.msg').val();

   $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"messages.php",
     data: "msg=" + msg,
     success: function(html) {
       $(html).prependTo('.messages');
     }
   });
});
});
```

this is my messages.php

```
   //insert into database
    $msg= $_POST['msg'];
    $db = dbConnect();
    $insert= "INSERT INTO messages (content)values ('$msg')";
    $db->query($insert);

   //get the recently added message and echo it

    $query = //select the ID of the added message
    $result = $db->($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc());
       echo $row['id'];
       echo $row['content'];
```

the part where im struggling, is how to `query` the message being submitted right after it was inserted to the database, so i could echo it in php, and fetch it via ajax.

```
 success: function(html) {
           $(html).prependTo('.messages');
         }
```

i know i need some unique identifier of the submitted message, but im not sure how to code it properly.

edit:

ok, the reason i needed to query the added entry, is to get the associated ID of that entry, because i will be using the ID for other functions. all i really need is a reference on my submitted data

Comment: An INSERT query doesn't return any results, so you can't use `$result->fetch_assoc()`. Why don't you just `echo $msg`?

Comment: You don't need to query the record again as you've got the fields that "make up" that record. What you do need however is the row id which you can get using the insert id function of mysql http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: @JLevett the reason i need to get the recent entry is i need the ID of that entry, because i will be using the ID for other functions. i hope that make sense

Comment: Does each row in `messages` have a unique id that auto_increments?

Comment: @Barmar the reason i wanted to query the entry is to get the ID of that entry and use it for other functions. thats why i cant just echo the msg.

Comment: Then use `db->insert_id`.

Comment: yes, it has unique id and its set to auto increment

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said use insert id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = $db->insert_id;
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = $id";
$result = $db->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['content'];
```

Answer (score -1):

use last inserted id function it can also help if you are inserting in two different table and inputing same row values

```
//insert query in this line
$lastid=mysqli_insert_id()//php function
$que = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table where id= '$lastid' ");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($que);
echo $r['id'];
```

hopes this help

Comment: The OP is using mysqli, not mysql. And mysql doesn't have a `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, it's called `mysql_insert_id()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I was giving the name of the mysql function, not the mysqli function, since Jose is answering with mysql.

Comment: last_insert_id is php function and its tagged in the question and mysql is old but works the issue is how to get the last inserted id not what to use mysqli or mysql

Comment: @JoseSamaniego But you can't use it like that, you need to do `mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")`.